# upstream sent no valid HTTP/1.0 header while reading response header from upstream when access https domain

Tags: nginx, https

When access my domain https://rancher1.208.com,the docker's nginx throw this error:

```
2019/06/11 00:19:42 [error] 6#6: *40 upstream sent no valid HTTP/1.0 header while reading response header from upstream, client: 101.24.11.112, server: rancher.208.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://172.19.104.231:4431/", host: "rancher1.208.com"
```

This is my ssl config:

```
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 ssl;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/conf.d/cert/rancher1.208.com/fullchain1.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/conf.d/cert/rancher1.208.com/privkey1.pem;

    server_name rancher1.208.com;
```

Where is going wrong?should I redirect 80 to 443?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check you proxy address to use https:

```
location / {
        proxy_pass https://rancher;
        index index.html index.htm;
    }
```

Pay attention the proxy_pass is https not http.